# Filter by Domain or Word using python

Tags: python, sockets, filter, hostname, gethostbyaddr

**Hello, im searching for some help.
I want to filter a print results in python.
I use this code:**

```
import socket
addr_range = "192.168.1.%d"
ip_address_up = []
ip_dns = []
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.settimeout(2.0)

for i in range(1, 254):
    try:
        ip = addr_range % i
        ip_dns.append(socket.gethostbyaddr(ip))
        ip_address_up.append(ip)
    except socket.herror as ex:
        pass

print (ip_dns)
```

**by: mouad (edited by me)**

So i have a lot of results, and i want to filter them like: just show results if domain is `.com`.

Or remove results by words, like: the hostname is vodafone for example, and i want if hostname have the word vodafone don't appear.

Thanks!